# How do I fix website temporarily displaying Open Graph Protocol Tags?

Tags: node.js, nginx, facebook-opengraph

I've recently pushed a website to live and for some odd reason, when I visit the website my Open Graph Meta tags are temporarily displaying and then switching to the correct title. It renders as "$OG_TITLE" for like 1-2 seconds then renders the title correctly. I want it to immediately render the title of the website when the page loads. This is happening for All routes of the pages throughout the website.

The website is on AWS using EC2 Nginx Configuation.

So my question is how do I make my website fully display the dynamic OG_Title tags? This is happening in local and live. In addition, I don't know if this has something to do with it but if I switch my localhost to let's say `localhost:5000` (my backend server) I don't have the problem but when I use `localhost:3312` (my client) the problem occurs.

Link to website where the problem is: https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/

Here is my code and what I've done.

Configuration: NodeJS backend with expressJS as back-end framework, ReactJS front-end for the view. I tried to also install react-helmet on each route to see if it would fix my problem and it didn't also.

I have a lot of code so I'll only be adding the parts relevant to my question.

NodeJS server code (server.js):

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
var MetaTags = require("./metaTags");
const router = express.Router();

var filePath = path.join(__dirname + "/../build/index.html");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  const urlArray = request.originalUrl.split(".");
  fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", function(err, data) {
    var metadata = {
      title: "Nursing Home Page",
      description:
        "Provides top quality nursing care for patients around Sacramento.",
      canonical: "https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/"
    };
    if (urlArray.length == 1) {
      metadata = MetaTags.urlString.getMetaData("/");
    }
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, metadata.title);
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, metadata.description);
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_CANONICAL/g, metadata.canonical);
    response.send(data);
  });
});

// Serve static files on server
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../build"));

app.get("*", (request, response) => {
  //response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../build/index.html"));
  const urlArray = request.originalUrl.split(".");
  fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", function(err, data) {
    var metadata = {
      title: "Mountain Manor Home Page",
      description:
        "Provides top quality nursing care for patients around Sacramento.",
      canonical: "https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/"
    };
    if (urlArray.length == 1) {
      metadata = MetaTags.urlString.getMetaData(urlArray[0]);
    }
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_TITLE/g, metadata.title);
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_DESCRIPTION/g, metadata.description);
    data = data.replace(/\$OG_CANONICAL/g, metadata.canonical);
    response.send(data);
  });
});

app.listen(2121, () => {
  console.log(`Server successfully started`);
});
```

**Index.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      href="/images/mmfavicon.png"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="16x16"
    />
    <title>$OG_TITLE</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="$OG_TITLE" />
    <meta name="description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="$OG_DESCRIPTION" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

MetaTags.js (contains the information on the specific pages but in a separate file)

```
var _ = require("lodash");

var urlsList = [
  {
    url: "/",
    title: "Home Page",
    description:
      "Provides top quality nursing care for patients.",
    canonical: "https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/"
  },
  {
    url: "/skilledNursing",
    title: "Mountain Manor Skilled Nursing",
    description:
      "Mountain Manor provides Skilled Nursing",
    canonical: "https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/skilledNursing"
  },
  {
    url: "/aboutUs",
    title: "Mountain Manor About Us",
    description: "Mountain Manor History | About Us | Accolades",
    canonical: "https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/aboutUs"
  },
  {
    url: "/contactUs",
    title: "Mountain Manor Contact Page",
    description: "Mountain Manor Contact",
    canonical: "https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/contactUs"
  },
  {
    url: "/careers",
    title: "Mountain Manor Careers Page",
    description: "Mountain Manor Careers and Job Openings",
    canonical: "https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/careers"
  }
];

var urlString = {
  getMetaData: function(reqUrl) {
    var splitUrl = reqUrl.split("/");

    var metaIndex = _.findIndex(urlsList, function(object) {
      return object.url == reqUrl;
    });
    if (metaIndex == -1) {
      return metaTags.homePage();
    } else {
      return urlsList[metaIndex];
    }
  }
};

var metaTags = {
  homePage: function() {
    const reqObject = {
      title: "Mountain Manor Home Page",
      description:
        "Mountain Manor Skilled Nursing & Assisted Living provides top quality nursing care for patients",
      canonical: "https://mountainmanorskillednursing.com/"
    };
    return reqObject;
  }
};

module.exports = {
  metaTags,
  urlString
};
```

Nginx Config

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 location / {
   root /var/www/mountainmanor/build;
   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
 server_name xxxxxxxx;
 return 301 $scheme://mountainmanorskillednursing.com$request_uri;
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://xxxxxxx:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
}
server {
 location / {
   root /var/www/mountainmanor/build;
   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    server_name mountainmanorskillednursing.com www.mountainmanorskillednursing.com; # managed by Certbot
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://xxxxxxx:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mountainmanorskillednursing.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}server {
    if ($host = www.mountainmanorskillednursing.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mountainmanorskillednursing.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 listen 80 ;
 listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name mountainmanorskillednursing.com www.mountainmanorskillednursing.com;
}
```

I expect the output of the website to display the dynamic OG title tags throughout every route correctly but is only temporarily displaying it on page refresh.

Comment: what is your nginx config? I think in your case the file is being server as it is from nginx and there is no replacement of those tags at all https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfFfT.png

Comment: ugh.. I don't know how to copy my nginx config in Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Also I think my problem is my nginx config is serving my client rather than my back-end node server cause on development my back-end server is listening on port 5000 and when I navigate to that port I don't have any problems at all. It displays the dynamic OG tags for every route.

Comment: You can run `nginx -T` to get the config, i think you have `try_files` which is serving the requests

Comment: Yeah it has to do with my nginx config cause when I serve my back-end 5000 port the dynamic OG tags are displaying just fine. However, on my client which is 3312 thats the problem I'm having. Also for my nginx config the only try files I have are for the 404 pages. I'll try and share my nginx config later today.

Comment: Okay i tested the nginx config and it said the syntax was just fine. I posted my nginx config.

Comment: Your `location /` is being served by `root /var/www/mountainmanor/build;`, so why would you get the `nodejs` updated value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Should I remove "/" from my nginx config?

Comment: Remove the `location /` block completely and change `/api` to `/`, so that the updated pages are delivered from your nodejs api

Comment: In my nodejs I have my api serving express routes via express such as `app.use('/api', Login); if I remove the `/api` from my nginx config will that affect the back-end api? Also, is it possible you can tell me where I should remove that `location /`? I have it in multiple locations in my nginx config. I think certbot put it there when I was trying to get the website https enabled.